# Sencha Touch 2.4.1, bug with iPhone scrolling

Tags: sencha-touch, senchatouch-2.4

A bug appeared after I upgraded the sencha touch fw from 2.3 to 2.4.2.

From time to time, when I scroll down or up the application, all the page scroll, and a black screen appear up or down...

This issue i random on iPhone.

Some people already experimented this issue ?

Thank you !

Comment: Could you provide an example? I have not seen this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

We have investigate this issue. 
This issue appear when we try to scroll a list and some  link are in the item template. 
Scrolling with a finger on the link make the screen moves, scrolling with a finger outside the link the list scroll normally.
For the moment, as the application is in production, we just downgrade sencha to 2.3.1, and it's working.
So we stick on sencha 2.3.1 for the moment, and try to address the issue later.